# Permission denied while reading contents of a Windows directory

Tags: perl, directory, permission-denied

I have a script that reads the contents of a directory. But the script can't open the directory because permission is denied. I am working on Windows, and I've tried to run the script as administrator, but that didn't help.

Here's the code:

```
sub dir_put {
  my $dir_name = shift;

  open DIR, $dir_name or die "Error reading directory: $!";
  my @array;
  my @return;

  while ($_ = readdir(DIR)){
    next if $_ eq "." or $_ eq "..";
    if (-d $_) {
      @return = dir_put($_);
      unshift(@array, @return);
      next;
    }
    unshift (@array, "$dir_name\\$_");
  }

  @array;
}
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `opendir`, not `open`.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open directory with `open`, it isn't file. For opening directories there is `opendir` function in perl.

Try:

```
opendir my $dir, $dir_name or die "Error reading directory: $!";
my @array;
my @return;
while ( readdir $dir ) {
...
```

Also you better use modules from cpan like `File::Find` or [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule)

```
perl -MFile::Find::Rule -E "say $_ for File::Find::Rule->in('F:\\Films');"
```